# WARNING: no logs are available with the 'none' log driver

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

I am following below url for logging driver

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#configure-the-default-logging-driver

now, I want to remove this logging driver

**I have remove file(daemon.json) from /etc/docker folder too.**

But when I build container, system should always showing me warning

```
WARNING: no logs are available with the 'none' log driver
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: To remove your logging driver, put this in your daemon.json (you probably shound not have deleted it)

{
  "log-driver": "syslog"
}


I don't think you can get ride of this warning

Comment: for me, I have to update the docker-compose version to 1.29 or higher which resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Finally solved.**

1) Delete `daemon.json` file from `/etc/docker` folder.

2) Restart docker service.

Answer (score 3):

My case.

In file `docker-compose.yml` it is very possible that you have:

```
logging:
    driver: none
```

To get rid of the warning `WARNING: no logs are available with the 'none' log driver` you should comment or remove those 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

By default `/etc/docker/daemon.json` does not exist. The default driver is json-file. To verify current driver use

docker info | grep Logging

Logging Driver: fluentd

I use fluentd (td-agent) so my `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
   "log-driver": "fluentd",
   "log-opts": {
   "fluentd-address": "127.0.0.1:24224"
              }
}
```

For details about logging, divers see
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/