# docker logs <C> returns nothing

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I build and run a docker image with

```
docker run --detach --name api rkevinburton/myagsourceapi
```

But when I 'docker ps -a' I get a message that this container has exited.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
ee956fbf1d7f        rkevinburton/myagsourceapi   "/bin/bash"         10 seconds ago      Exited (0) 8 seconds ago                       api
```

So I want to find out why it exited. So I issue the command

```
docker logs ee
```

But this command returns nothing. As the docker host is a Windows machine I looked on ~\AppData\Local\Docker but the information in the log*.txt or install-log.* didn't seem to help me any. How can I get more information on why the container 'Exited'?

Comment: Try to run it using `docker run -it --name api rkevinburton/myagsourceapi` and see if you get anything

Comment: What is the return of `docker info |grep -i log` ? Try to just `docker run -it hello-world` and then read the logs of the started container. It should contain the same output you read when you run the container.

Comment: To see what's going on run without --detach.
Also its possible (though not probable) that you have configured a different logging driver in the docker deamon (like gelf) in which case docker logs won't work.

Comment: When I try to run in interactive mode I get:

`AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Then there is no interactive session to browse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker containers exit when their main process finishes. That is why you don't get any logs.

> The docker logs command batch-retrieves logs present **at the time of execution**.
>
> (see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

#### An example:

The following will create a new container and start it:

```
docker run -d --name=my_test_container alpine ping -c 20 127.0.0.1
[----run----]   [--------name--------] [image][-----command------]
```

Try to use the following, before `ping` command stops:

- `docker logs my_test_container`
- `docker logs --follow my_test_container`

The first one shows what has been printed out by `ping` (until then) and the second one gives you logs as `ping` prints out new lines.

After 20  ping requests, the ping command finishes and the container stops.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
e8f371000146        alpine              "ping -c 20 127.0.0.1"   29 seconds ago      Exited (0) 9 seconds ago                       my_test_container
```

Comment: My Node-Red container is running and processing its flows. However, the logs on the console still outputs nothing.

Comment: @ShadowGames check if your case has to do with setting the log driver to `none` in the container settings. More: [WARNING: no logs are available with the 'none' log driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182256/warning-no-logs-are-available-with-the-none-log-driver).

Comment: My log driver is set to json-file, so I'm wondering why there're no logs being output :/